# Migration from eclipse 3.6 to eclipse 4.6 for Rcp applicaton : not able render part on workbench

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am  trying to soft migrate our Rcp application from E3.x(indigo) application to E4.6(Neon1) ,

trying following approach..

I have added Application.e4xmi file in our perspective plugin,modelled upto trimmed window.(in plugin extention org.eclipse.core.runtime.products->applicationXMI point to Application.e4xmi)).

In my exisiting project exporer plugin , i have added fragment.e4xmi referring the Application.e4xmi's trimmed window id for the project explorer part.
also in plugin.xml->extension i have added fragment.e4xmi under org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model.

Problem is, I am not able to see the part(project explorer) on workbench which is added in fragment.e4xmi

Comment: Are you talking about the standard Project Explorer view? This is a 3.x compatibility mode view and won't work in a pure e4 RCP. Converting a 3.x RCP to a pure e4 RCP is very hard work.

Comment: I am able to add the 3.x  project explorer view in workbench with help of e4 compatibility layer but it is not functional at all. getting org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Could not find satisfiable constructor in org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView error

Comment: The compatibility layer requires a great deal of initialization. You can't just try to use a CompatibilityView part directly from the e4xmi.